# airflow ssh connection , connection type not displaying

Tags: airflow

I am trying to add connection to the airflow server. I wanted to have ssh added. only the below listed 5 is being displayed. Can you point me how to add the ssh connection ?

[image]

Comment: I figured out pip install apache-airflow-providers-ssh will get that done Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Airflow < 2.0.0` all connections are available by default.

In `Airflow >= 2.0.0` Airflow automatically discovers which providers additional capabilities (connections, extra links etc...) once you install provider package and re-start Airflow, those become automatically available. More information about this can be found in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/index.html#extending-airflow-connections-and-extra-links-via-providers). Specifically for SSH connection you will need to install [SSH provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-ssh
```

Comment: it still isn't working after doing this, I've tried restarting airflow so many different way but the new connection type doesn't show up

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch Airflow has several components. Make sure you restart the webserver and after rest that the package is avaiable on it. Some deployments are rolled back to some default configuration after reset you will need to check how your instance is configured.

Comment: would you mind elaborating here, I restarted the webserver and the package is available but it still doesn't show up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73921566/airflow-conn-types-missing-even-after-installing-the-correct-provider

Answer (score 1):

In `Airflow >= 2.0.0` if have installed the providers after you started the airflow and you are directly going to the UI and refreshing the page and expecting the provider to show up then it won't happen.

It is must that you will have to re-start the airflow once again in order for the latest provider that you have installed to show up in the dropdownlist.