# No module named 'airflow.providers.ssh' on AWS Airflow (Amazon MWAA)

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I need to use sshoperator in a DAG on AWS Airflow (Amazon MWAA), so I imported the following library in my DAG file

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator
```

It seems sshoperator has been defined in paramiko library, so I have added the following modules to requiremets.txt file as well

- paramiko>=2.6.0
- pysftp>=0.2.9
- sshtunnel>=0.1.4

But still, I'm getting the following error when I browse DAGs

```
Broken DAG: 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ssh_operator.py", 
  line from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.ssh'
```

My underestanding was sshoperator in an essential and built in operators in Airflow, so technically I shouldn't add any extra libraries or plugins to Airflow.

Answer (score 5):

**This command fixed it for me:**

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-ssh
```

Comment: Works great. Note that for me, does not require a restart of any of the airflow components, but did require waiting several seconds for the change to kick in.

Comment: Ah, just noticed this though: You'll have to restart airflow to create an ssh connection according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66471500/6952495)

Comment: where do you input that command? do you have to ssh into the fargate instance for MWAA?

Comment: @eljusticiero67 not sure if the self managed MWAA allows this, I believe you should have given it in requirement.txt when you were setting it up.

Comment: Don't think this is relevant to MWAA. You don't have access to the server the airflow instance is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Was researching something similar and believe that I found the answer to both of our questions... According to [Docker Questions](https://dockerquestions.com/2020/11/16/airflow-no-module-named-airflow-providers-or-airflow-contrib-providers/)...

> Providers package is no longer included with Airflow, but you can separately install them with pip using the specific backport package

It looks like there is a backport for ssh [here](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-ssh/). So probably just have to add that to your requirements.txt?

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding apache-airflow-providers-ssh==1.3.0 to requirements.txt

Comment: the only disatvantage is that once you add extra modules via the requirements.txt, it then prevents you from running certain airflow cli commands. The worse being, you cant run a backfill