# Airflow conn types missing even after installing the correct provider?

Tags: http, connection, airflow

Learning apache airflow and I'm trying to create a new connection type the correct way, but it still doesn't show up. I am working within a virtual environment on WSL2 through VS Code, and my terminal looks like this `(sandbox) nick@GameCube:~$`

This is what my pip list within the venv shows

[image]

But these are my only conn types within the airflow UI (I am running `airflow webserver` within the venv too)

[image]

You can see that all the other installed conn types show up, but `http` doesn't for some reason. Why does this happen? I have tried restarting vscode, killing the webserver process and restarting it, etc but it still doesn't show!

Comment: I would guess that you are installing your instance in a non consistant way? You show Airflow 2.1 but Http provider 4.0.0 has mininum requirment of Airflow 2.2. Since you are new to Airflow i suggest to install Airflow according to instructions in the docs with constraints before you make changes. Http provider comes by default with Airflow you dont need to install it specifically.

Comment: @EladKalif you were exactly right, I needed to install a lower version of the provider that worked with my lower version of airflow. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apache-airflow-providers-http==4.0.0` is not compatible with `apache-airflow==2.1.0`

To solve your issue you need to downgrade http provider to a version compatible with Airflow 2.1.0

Noting that Http provider is installed by default with Airflow if you need to bump its version make sure you set it to compatible version.

In larger context I suggest to install Airflow from constraints as suggested in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#installation-tools). This will prevent case of unstable environment as Airflow brings many dependencies and it guarantees a working environment of Airflow. You can upgrade providers to newer versions but you will need to take a closer look on each upgrade. You can read about it in this [doc: Installing/upgrading/downgrading providers separately from Airflow core](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#installing-upgrading-downgrading-providers-separately-from-airflow-core).