# How do I make Postgres Conn Type available on Airflow

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I have recently installed Airflow and want to make use of the Postgres operator to create tables and insert some values. When I tried to create a connection string I couldn't find Postgres in the `Conn type`. Then I installed the Postgres provider using `pip install apache-airflow-providers-postgres`. It was successfully installed but it did not appear in the `conn type` after restarting airflow. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What version of Airflow are you using? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73921566/airflow-conn-types-missing-even-after-installing-the-correct-provider?rq=2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airflow conn types missing even after installing the correct provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73921566/airflow-conn-types-missing-even-after-installing-the-correct-provider)